# Find the integer $'n'$ for which the given limit is a finite non-zero number.

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

> Find the integer $'n'$ for which the given limit is a finite non-zero number.
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{\cos^2 x -\cos x -e^x \cos x + e^x - \frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$$

I'm almost blind regarding this one. All I've done yet is a simple factorization for the numerator:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{(\cos x - 1)(\cos x - e^x) - \frac{x^3}{2} }{x^n}$$

Not sure how to go on from here. Taylor series sounds a way for this but it will get too lengthy! I did try to input the expansion series for the functions, but that isn't getting in my way.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{\left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots -1 \right) \left[ \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \dots\right)\\ - \left( 1 + \frac{x}{1!}+ \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots \right) \right] - \frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$$

First of all, we're expected to solve such questions in 3 minutes and am not sure whether using Taylor Series will be the best option here. Although, I will still appreciate if someone helps me out in doing it with Taylor Series too. As am more interested in knowing about it's application rather than scoring marks without much knowledge.

Comment: Most probably seems 2, just guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the numerator that you nicely wrote and let us use the usual Taylor series to get $$\cos(x)-1=-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ $$\cos(x)-e^x=-x-x^2-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$(\cos(x)-1)\times (\cos(x)-e^x)=\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^5}{24}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

$$\cfrac{(\cos x - 1)(\cos x - e^x) - \frac{x^3}{2} }{x^n}=\frac{x^{3-n}}{2}+\frac{x^{5-n}}{24}+\cdots$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I do get the point that I'll be left with: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{\frac{x^4}{2} + \frac{x^5}{12} - \frac{x^5}{24} }{x^n}$$ 

How to continue from here, Sir?

Comment: Yep! Got it now, Mr. Claude! Am now progressing towards the love for Taylor Series finally :D

Comment: I think you have made some mistake somewhere. May be I did other ? Who knows ? But, more serious, I think that my result is correct. You must take a sufficient number of terms in the expansions.

Comment: Sorry sir, but I guess it should have been (in your solution) : $$\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{\left( \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^4}{2} + \frac{x^5}{12} - \dots \right) - \frac{x^3}{2} }{x^n} \\
\lim_{x\to 0} \cfrac{\frac{x^4}{2} + \frac{x^5}{12} - \frac{x^5}{24}}{x^n} $$

Comment: I hope and wish you become loving Taylor series. It is an incredibly powerful tool for limits, asymptotic behavior, approach to limits and asymptotes, integration, approximations ... and so on ! If I am wrong, I am have stupid during all my loooong life. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your help and baring patience with me! I really appreciate the way you've been helping me and others over here. Thanks again.

Comment: You are right ! I had a typo. Fixed now. Be sure that you are very welcome.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thanks again, Mr. Claude!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Mr. Claude! I was away from keyboard due to some unavoidable reasons. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can write this same limit even as

$\lim_{x\to 0}=\frac{1}{x^n}*[(cosx-1)^2-(e^x-1)(\cos x)+(e^x-1)-\frac{x^3}{3}]$